# Post JSON getting null object

Tags: jquery, json, post

I am writing an asp.net web form application and trying to post data from a form but in my controller I am getting posted object as null.

Get requests are working fine.
I have done similar work many time but the only difference is that application is running with HTTPS this time and I don't think that would make any difference.

MY Model

[image]

my jquery post

```
function AddContactClicked() {

var contactMeetings = { name: "Shafaqat Ali", completeAddress: "completeAddress" };
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(contactMeetings),
    url: "/api/contact/AddContact",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}).done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
}).fail(function (info) {

});
}
```

controller

```
[Route("AddContact")]
[HttpPost]
// POST: api/Contacts
public void Post([FromBody] ContactMeeting contactMeetings)
{
}
```

[image]

Chrome developer console

[image]

**update**

this worked.

```
var contactMeetings = { name: "Shafaqat Ali", completeAddress: "completeAddress" };
var jqxhr = $.post('/api/contact/AddContact', contactMeetings)
    .success(function () {
        alert("posted");
    })
    .error(function () {
        $('#message').html("Error posting the update.");
    });
```

Comment: write code rather then post pic of code ?

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(contact)` read full info [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: try data: JSON.stringify(contact)

Comment: Just change the parameter name same as passing object name change your contactMeetings to contact or pass data as data: contactMeetings:contact,

Comment: JSON.stringify(contact) also did not work.